# Xpath: Exceptions in query based on parent value

Tags: xpath, parent-child

I need to take all `"//ul/li[not(@*)][count(*)=0]"` except those that have `<div>` parent. I've tried `"//not(div)/ul/li[not(@*)][count(*)=0]"`, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Does anyone know, how can i deal with that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest XPath expression that selects the wanted nodes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
//ul[not(parent::div)]/li[not(@*|*)]
```

Or:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()[not(self:div)]/ul/li[not(@*|*)]
```

Both selects such `ul` when it's the root element, also.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//*[not(self::div)]/li[not(@*) and not(*)]
```

which can be slightly abbreviated to the equivalent:

```
//*[not(self::div)]/li[not(@*|*)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  
1) it has a parcing error - i think it's because of missed bracet:  
not  
`//*[not(self::div)]/li[not(@*) and not(*)]`  
but  
`//*[not(self::div)]/li[not(@*) and not(*)]`  
2) with that corrected expression i've got one unwanted result

Comment: @CodeJunkie: Thanks for the good catch -- I corrected the two expressions and now they are syntactically correct. As for getting one unwanted result, could you, please, provide the simplest possible XML document (by editing your question) on which this can be demonstrated? Maybe you misstated your requirements, or missed an additional requirement